# Spring Boot configure Jetty init parameter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

For context purposes, I'm in the process of upgrading an existing codebase from Spring Boot 1.5.3 to 1.5.14. As part of that upgrade, some of the existing tests it had started failing because of the StrictHttpFirewall that was added, which is now complaining that some redirect urls contain the `jsessionid`:

```
2018-06-27 18:04:33.137  WARN 15406 --- [ qtp10915321-23] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel     : /mock/oauth/authorize;jsessionid=node0hhrv3r9m7c6i3ksjrhkeql4m0.node0

org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String ";"
```

Even though I have session tracking mode set to cookies, Jetty is still also writing it into the URL apparently. According to the [Jetty docs](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/session-management.html), I could disable that by setting `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.SessionIdPathParameterName` to `none`, but when I tried doing that with a `ServletContextInitializer`:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
  servletContext.setInitParameter("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.SessionIdPathParameterName", "none");
}
```

It doesn't work, seemingly because it's executed after Jetty has already interrogated that property (based on my debugging breakpoints at least).

The couple tests that started failing are testing some oauth2 auth code flow behaviors, and the redirects to the authorization endpoint are now problematic.

Any suggestions?